# Reversing a list using List.fold_right

Tags: list, ocaml

I just started learning `ocaml` recently and I am currently on a problem where I want to reverse a list (i.e. `[1;2;3]` to `[3;2;1]`) using `List.fold_right`.

**From I've attempted so far:**

From my understanding,

```
List.fold_right (fun x y -> x+y) [1;2;3] 0
```

will results in `1+(2+(3+0))`

So I think I can reverse the list by doing

```
List.fold_right (fun x y -> y::x) [1;2;3] []
```

Which in theory should give me

`1 swap (2 swap (3 swap []))` into `1 swap ( [] 3 2)` which ultimately becomes `3 2 1`.

However, there seems to be a type mismatch in here?

Additionally, if I were to change the function into `(fun x y -> y@x)`, I was able to successfully reverse list within a list (i.e. `[[1];[2];[3]]` into `[[3];[2];[1]]`).

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

The type of `List.fold_right` is `('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b -> 'b`. If you look at the type of the function to be folded, it's `'a -> 'b -> 'b`. In other words, the first parameter is a new element of the input list and the second parameter is the accumulated answer. In your case, then, the first paramter is an int (say) and the second parameter is a list of ints. This is why you can't use `(fun x y -> y :: x)`. The first parameter `x` is the next int (not a list).

If you look at your example expression 1 + (2 + (3 + 0)), which is in fact a great way to think about it, you'll see that it's quite difficult to reverse the list this way. The first value processed by the function is supposed to be at the front of the result. This isn't a natural way to process the list. Reversing a list with `List.fold_left` is much easier (in fact, it's trivial).

If you really want to do this, what you need to do is to add each new value to the end of the accumulated result. This isn't impossible, it's just a poor way to process lists. Here is a function that adds a value to the end of a list:

```
let add_to_end x l = l @ [x]
```

Answer (score 1):

> So I think I can reverse the list by doing
>
> `List.fold_right (fun x y -> y::x) [1;2;3] []` Which in theory should
>   give me
>
> 1 swap (2 swap (3 swap [])) into 1 swap ( [] 3 2) which ultimately
>   becomes 3 2 1.

First of all, in `List.fold_right (fun x y -> y::x) [1;2;3] []`, initially, `y is []`, `x is 3`, you can't do `y::x` on this case, i.e., you can't do `[]::3`

Also what do you mean by **swap**?

As other answers indicated, you have to give a `append` function.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the list item to the end of the accumulated list.  You generally could only operate on the head of a list so you can't use the cons (`::`) operator.  But you can treat the item as a list and concatenate (`@`) them together.  Just that both operands need to be lists so place the item being added in a list.

```
List.fold_right (fun x acc -> acc @ [x]) [1; 2; 3] []
```

Comment: Ah, I understand.

When I'm doing the concatenation, it will be taking the form of [some list] and an element, so I obviously can't do list::element, so I'd have to do concatenate using list@[element] instead.

That was unclear to me originally. Thanks!